# what is the meaning of the following line in php smarty?

Tags: php

I'm new to smarty and I'm seeing this line

```
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="
   {$system['system_url']}/themes/{$system['theme']}/images/favicon.png" />
```

This line is used to set favicon but they can use direct the image url "images/favicon.png" so why they used

Comment: they use it to make it dynamic based on your system environment

Comment: Are you using MVC?

Comment: No MVC. It is smarty php template engine.

Answer (score 1):

It is a best practice to isolate different resources as much as possible. Referencing a static file such as a favicon directly creates a direct link between the web framework and web layout.

Using the types of variables you see in your example, makes the path address to the favicon dynamic so if the app where to be moved, or renamed, the links between layout and framework would still work without needing to manually change all path addresses.